# aligning row content to the right horizontally html

Tags: html, css, image, grid, row

I have a text and a small image that I want to align horizontally to the right:

```
    <div class="row float-right">
      <div class="title" >Stream Chat</div>
      <img src="~assets/chat.svg" />
    </div>
    <!-- rest of the code -->
    <div class"row">
    ...
```

I want both to be on the same line next to each other not underneath eachother. Ican use `float-right` and move them to the right but the issue is first the img goes under the text and second the row moves to the right of the below row and they stay in the same line! How can I fix it in a way that the text and img stay level and to the right of the row?

Comment: if you are using latest bootstrap. use "align-items-end" class instead of "float-right".
else in custom css instead of adding float right to "row" add it to the children and check.

Comment: With the currently provided code, its impossible to replicate the problem, therefor hard to help you resolve it. Please provide a working code snippet of this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE FLEXBOX!! It's definitely the easiest way to do this

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-end;
align-items:center;
border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id='txt'>Stream Chat</div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
</div>
```